# Parsing script log using python

Tags: python, parsing, text

**How to get a some details out of the following script log.**

---

***Input.txt***

```
#Date: 04-Jul-2020 01:55:54
SL|INFO|-----sql_query------
        Update Table1 set sts='Process data--Started' where batch_id=30;
-----sql_query_end------
#Date: 04-Jul-2020 01:55:54
--
#Date: 04-Jul-2020 01:55:54
SL|INFO|-----sql_query------
        Update Table2 set fm_sts='Process data--Started' where batch_id=30;
-----sql_query_end------
#Date: 04-Jul-2020 01:55:54
--
#Date: 04-Jul-2020 02:08:14
SL|INFO|-----sql_query------
        Update Table1 set sts='Process data--Complete' where batch_id=30;
-----sql_query_end------
#Date: 04-Jul-2020 02:08:14
--
#Date: 04-Jul-2020 02:08:14
SL|INFO|-----sql_query------
        Update Table2 set fm_sts='Process data--Complete' where batch_id=30;
-----sql_query_end------
#Date: 04-Jul-2020 02:08:15
```

***Required Output***

```
Batch_Id 30,Process data--Started at 04-Jul-2020 01:55:54,Process data--Completed at  04-Jul-2020 02:08:14
```

**strong text**What i have tried:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    data = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(f_input, lambda x: not x.startswith("Pulling Keys--Started")) if k]
    data = [''.join(x) for x in data]

print (data)
```

Kindly let me know what are the steps i have to follow to get the required output.

Comment: Thank you Aviv Yaniv, how can i make my posts better formatted going forward.

Comment: Put ``` before and after code

Answer (score 0):

We loop on the lines of the log:

1. If date header format: 
   1.1. If the first date: update start date 
   1.2. Update end date
2. Else: 
   2.1. If no batch ID fetched 
   2.1.1. Set Batch ID if exists

```
import re

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    lines = f_input.readlines()
    start_date = None
    end_date   = None
    DATE_HEADER = '#Date: '
    BATCH_ID_FORMAT = r'batch_id=(\d+)'
    batch_id = None
    for l in lines:
        if l.startswith(DATE_HEADER):
            parsed_date = l.replace(DATE_HEADER, '').strip()
            if not start_date:
                start_date = parsed_date
            end_date = parsed_date
        else:
            if not batch_id:
                m = re.search(BATCH_ID_FORMAT, l)
                if m:
                    batch_id = m.group().replace('batch_id=', '')

# Batch_Id 30, Process data--Started at 04-Jul-2020 01:55:54, Process data--Completed at  04-Jul-2020 02:08:15
print(f'Batch_Id {batch_id}, Process data--Started at {start_date}, Process data--Completed at  {end_date}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Process logs for each batch, sort them and group them based on `batch_id`, get the start time from first batch and the end time from last batch within each group and print it.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> with open('input.txt') as f_input:
>>>    data = f_input.read()
>>>
>>> fields = re.findall(r'#Date: (\S* \S*).*?Process data--(Started|Complete)'
                        r'.*?batch_id=(\d+);.*?#Date:', data, re.DOTALL)
>>>
>>> key = lambda t: t[2]
>>> for batch_id,grp in groupby(sorted(fields, key=key), key):
...     start, *_, end = grp
...     print (f'Batch_Id {batch_id},Process data--Started at {start[1]},'
               f'Process data--Completed at {end[3]}')
... 
Batch_Id 30,Process data--Started at Started,Process data--Completed at 04-Jul-2020 02:08:15
```